# Integrate Custom Post Type Events into Calendar

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, calendar

I've got a custom post type called Events on my site with a custom field called event_date created via Advanced Custom fields that stores its value in yymmdd format. Everything works just fine and I'm even able to list upcoming events sorted by event_date on my home page.

Trouble is, I'd also like to list these events in the Wordpress calendar widget by event_date and I can't seem to figure out how to go about doing that. I see that someone has created a function that allows the Wordpress calendar to show custom post types, however it grabs *all* custom post types and it can't filter by custom fields:

http://bajada.net/2010/07/15/adding-custom-post-types-to-get_calendar-and-the-calendar-widget

Can anyone offer any advice? I'd prefer not to use an event plugin since the ones I've tried are too complicated for the client or don't integrate nicely into what I've already built. However I'm open to using a calendar plugin that can tie into custom post types and fields. I just haven't been able to find one.